# MySQL trigger at specified time to create new entries into a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

My problem is this, I have a list of students stored and each student attends school on certain days of the week. I want to create a trigger that runs at midnight that check what day it just became and if a student attends that day, will make a new entry into the database for each student. I have one partially created with a while loop, but I know it isn't the best solution. One big issue with this as it is now is that it would draw all of the StudentId's, not the single ID from the row it is currently examining. There are three tables that this will access Students, Schedule and ClassSession. Students and Schedule are already generated and multiple rows in ClassSession containing a StudentId and CurrentDate would be the outcome.

```
CREATE EVENT NewDailyTables
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  DO
    CALL CreateDayTriggerWhile();

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `cnp_data`.`CreateDayTriggerWhile` ()
BEGIN
    SET @ThisEnd=0;
    SET @Count=0;
    SET @ThisId=0;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Schedule INTO @ThisEnd;
    WHILE @Count<@ThisEnd DO
        SELECT StudentId FROM Schedule INTO @ ThisId; /* takes all student id's. Unsure of how to write WHERE row=@count*/
        CALL CreateDayTriggerHelp(@ThisId);
    END WHILE;
END $$

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `cnp_data`.`CreateDayTriggerHelp` (IN ThisId INT)
BEGIN

    SET @DayName = DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE);
    IF (SELECT ThisId FROM Schedule WHERE @DayName=1)=true
        THEN
            INSERT INTO ClassSession (StudentId, CurrentDate)
                VALUES (ThisId, CURRENT_DATE);
        END IF;
END $$

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks for your insight!

Edit--

This is how schedule looks

```
StudentId-Monday-Tuesday-Wednesday-Thursday-Friday-Saturday-Sunday
   2374  -   0  -   1   -    0    -    1   -  0   -    0   -  0
```

It store a tinyint/BOOL on the days the students show up to class. How I want to have it working is that it checks the day and then sees if the student is supposed to show up that day to class and creates the new entry into ClassSchedule if so

Comment: this makes no sense SELECT ThisId FROM Schedule WHERE @DayName=1 @DayName is Tuesday how can it be 1? You need a loop that gets all  results of SELECT StudentId FROM Schedule Where columane  = DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE); and insert every stiendt id . and get rid of teh second procedure But please add also the table Schedule so that someone can write a correct procedure

Comment: I see what you mean. How I wanted it to work was that @DayName took place of the column name and examined if it was 0 or 1.

Comment: I just don't understand why you would do this. As and when a user wants some information, they can simply execute a query; that's normally how it works.

Comment: Also, this is not the way to store a schedule in an RDBMS. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is this.

```
INSERT INTO
ClassSession 
    (`StudentId` ,  `CurrentDate` )
SELECT
  `StudentId`,
  CURRENT_DATE
FROM
  schedule
Where  
  CASE
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) =  2 AND `Monday` = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) =  3 AND `Tuesday` = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) =  4 AND `Wednesday` = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) =  5 AND `Thursday` = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) =  6 AND `Friday` = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) =  6 AND `Saturday` = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) =  1 AND `Sunday` = 1 = 1 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END > 0
```

You don't need a stored procedure nor two of them.

Insert directly into schedule, the tricky part is your table and how to get the studentId needed.

[example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f5f7a/1)

Comment: Thank you for this insight. Using this as a guideline I have created a trigger that works as needed!